# What dictates the available Cipher Suites in GlassFish and Payara?

Tags: glassfish, cipher

I have the same version of Payara Server (4.1.1.154) running on two different machines. I do not have the same list of available cipher suites between the two. What determines the available cipher suites in Payara and GlassFish?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We needed to download the [Java Cryptography Extension](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) to get the Cipher Suites we we were looking for. Installation consisted of copying the local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar from the download into the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security directory, overwriting the existing copies.

Comment: I did exactly that (and restarted Payara5) but the list in 'Available Common Cipher Suites' did not change. It only shows two TLS_* suites. I need SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, as in Glassfish3 on Java 1.6. Any idea how that can be fixed?

Comment: And, by the way, jdk1.8.0_192 has the two policy files in both jre/lib/security/policy/limited and ditto .../unlimited. Unfortunately, replacing those four files didn't help, either.

Comment: @Per Lindenberg Did you find a solution? We are at Glassfish5 and our eliptic ciphers EEC are empty. But if we prompt all available ciphers from the command line with -jrunscript they are available. Glassfish does not recognizes them.